# ViceroyTrace errors from GameKit

Tags: ios, swift, gamekit

I'm seeing lots of these, and no idea how to address or fix them. Everything in my App seems to be working as expected. However, if someone can direct me to the underlying issue, I'd like to fix it. I'd be less concerned if they just showed up during match setup, but they seem to show up throughout the app lifetime. I also find that when I activate voice chat via the GKMatch, everything seems to hang for 5-10 seconds and then resumes, afterwards, I have audio chat between match participants. Both devices are running 13.4.1, and I'm building for 13.4

```
2020-05-15 10:51:40.110332-0700 Pegs[7280:1943586] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] OSPFParse_ParsePacketHeader:1083 Bad destination count=0
2020-05-15 10:51:40.111417-0700 Pegs[7280:1943586] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] OSPFParse_ParsePacketHeader:1100 Checksum=42050 doesn't match
2020-05-15 10:51:40.113793-0700 Pegs[7280:1943586] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] OSPFParse_ParsePacketHeader:1083 Bad destination count=0
2020-05-15 10:51:40.113881-0700 Pegs[7280:1943616] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] RemoveNominatedCandidatePair:977 failed with invalid index input: -1, candidate pair count: 3
2020-05-15 10:51:40.114566-0700 Pegs[7280:1943616] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] gckSessionCheckPendingConnections:1437 gckSessionCheckPendingConnections: iICEChecksLeft=0, iUnconnectedNodeCount=0, iDDsExpected=1
2020-05-15 10:51:40.123082-0700 Pegs[7280:1943586] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2714 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (808568607)
2020-05-15 10:51:40.123722-0700 Pegs[7280:1943586] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] gckSessionCheckPendingConnections:1437 gckSessionCheckPendingConnections: iICEChecksLeft=0, iUnconnectedNodeCount=0, iDDsExpected=0
2020-05-15 10:51:43.423820-0700 Pegs[7280:1943604] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] AGPSessionRecvFrom:1954 0x1291465b0 sack: SEARCH FAILURE SERIAL NUMBER (00000000) FROM (3031C71F)...
2020-05-15 10:51:43.611955-0700 Pegs[7280:1943094] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] -[VCAudioRelayIO didUpdateBasebandCodec:]:307 Callback function not registered. CodecType[] SampleRate[24000.000000]
2020-05-15 10:51:44.782451-0700 Pegs[7280:1943625] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] VCAudioReceiver_DiscardQueueExcess:566 AudioReceiver is NULL
2020-05-15 10:51:49.566011-0700 Pegs[7280:1943604] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] AGPSessionRecvFrom:1954 0x1291465b0 sack: SEARCH FAILURE SERIAL NUMBER (00000001) FROM (3031C71F)...
2020-05-15 10:51:49.581831-0700 Pegs[7280:1943604] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] AGPSessionRecvFrom:1954 0x1291465b0 sack: SEARCH FAILURE SERIAL NUMBER (00000002) FROM (3031C71F)...
2020-05-15 10:51:49.589608-0700 Pegs[7280:1943604] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] AGPSessionRecvFrom:1954 0x1291465b0 sack: SEARCH FAILURE SERIAL NUMBER (00000003) FROM (3031C71F)...
2020-05-15 10:51:49.598690-0700 Pegs[7280:1943604] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] AGPSessionRecvFrom:1954 0x1291465b0 sack: SEARCH FAILURE SERIAL NUMBER (00000004) FROM (3031C71F)...
2020-05-15 10:51:49.623733-0700 Pegs[7280:1943094] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] openLogDump:68 failed to open /var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.VideoConference/logs/20200515-105149-1509645760-CallSettings.calldump with error 1
2020-05-15 10:51:49.626865-0700 Pegs[7280:1943094] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] -[VCWifiAssistManager queryUserPreference]:122 Can not get dictionary
2020-05-15 10:51:49.652779-0700 Pegs[7280:1943604] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] AGPSessionRecvFrom:1954 0x1291465b0 sack: SEARCH FAILURE SERIAL NUMBER (00000005) FROM (3031C71F)...
2020-05-15 10:51:49.664910-0700 Pegs[7280:1943604] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] AGPSessionRecvFrom:1954 0x1291465b0 sack: SEARCH FAILURE SERIAL NUMBER (00000006) FROM (3031C71F)...
2020-05-15 10:51:49.755070-0700 Pegs[7280:1943643] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] VCSDInfoIsSrcDstInfoMatchedWithIP:100 Invalid VCSourceDestinationInfoMode:0!
2020-05-15 10:51:49.756962-0700 Pegs[7280:1943643] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] _VTP_HealthPrint:2498 Cannot print health for invalid connection index.
2020-05-15 10:51:49.758008-0700 Pegs[7280:1943094] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] ICEGetCandidates:578 /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AVConference/AVConference-1624.34/ICE.subproj/Sources/ICE.c:578: ProcessCollectionResponse failed (8015000C)
2020-05-15 10:51:54.804849-0700 Pegs[7280:1943094] [ViceroyTrace] VideoConference [ERROR] -[VideoConference inviteDataForParticipantID:callID:remoteInviteData:nonCellularCandidateTimeout:error:]:886 VideoConference: CALLID MISMATCH 0x129169db0 client callID 6163260860 internal callID 0
2020-05-15 10:51:54.810911-0700 Pegs[7280:1943094] [ViceroyTrace] VCCallSession [ERROR] -[VCCallSession startConnectionWithParticipantID:callID:usingInviteData:isCaller:capabilities:idsSocket:destination:error:]_block_invoke:2303 Reporting not available (no backends)
2020-05-15 10:51:54.812938-0700 Pegs[7280:1943642] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] VCAudioReceiver_DiscardQueueExcess:566 AudioReceiver is NULL
```